# Difference between 'cout<<cout' and 'cout<<&cout' in c++?

Tags: c++, cout

I want to know actual difference between `cout<<cout` and `cout<<&cout` in `c++`? In my compiler `cout<<cout` returns `0x477864` & `cout<<&cout` returns `0x477860` at any time.It shows it has 1 digit of difference between them.What are the significance of these?

Comment: http://ideone.com/JfKmxd

Comment: Maybe an issue with multiple inheritance? Like, cout could implicitly converts to a pointer of one of its base class, while &cout gives the address of the first base class of cout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do this:

```
cout << cout;
```

You are relying on the stream's implicit conversion to `void*`. This value is used (pre-c++11) for testing the state of the stream. It is unspecified what the value actually is, it just needs to be NULL if the stream is in a fail state, and a non NULL otherwise. Maybe it's returning the address of a member of the object, but it's not really important, and is implementation defined.

When you do this:

```
cout << &cout;
```

That is getting the actual address of `cout`.

Note that in C++11 and beyond, the first one, `cout << cout;`, will no longer compile, because the implicit conversion to `void*` no longer exists. Instead there is an explicit conversion to `bool` to serve the same purpose.